# Angular 2 dynamically compiled module is not providing services

Tags: angular

I have a module that I am dynamically importing and compiling. I am able to compile and render components using the following:

```
// Module is imported and available in the importedModule variable

const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(<any>importedModule);

const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
    comp.componentType === route.component
);

const component = this.container.createComponent(factory);
```

The above works and displays the component. However, If I attempt to inject a service in the constructor of the component using:

```
constructor(private applicationService:ApplicationService) {
}
```

I get the following error:

> No provider for ApplicationService!

I am providing the service in the same module that is being dynamically imported:

```
@NgModule({
...
providers: [
    ApplicationService
  ]
})
export class TestModule {
}
```

The service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ApplicationService {
}
```

Is there another method I should be calling to get the services working?

Answer (score 0):

> Do not specify app-wide singleton providers in a shared module. A lazy-loaded module that imports that shared module makes its own copy of the service.

Source: [https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#why-*userservice*-isn-t-shared](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#why-_userservice_-isn-t-shared)

With this info in mind, I think your dynamically created module is in the same situation with the lazy-loaded module. So the solution would be to provide it in your app module.